# How to encrypt with AES-256 GCM in Delphi

Tags: delphi, cryptography, aes-gcm

is there a way or a library to encrypt/decrypt values with AES-256 mode GCM in Delphi? as it seems that most libraries do not support it like DCPcrypt or LockBox.

or maybe there is a Windows API that could handle that.

thanks in advance.

Comment: The Windows [CNG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/cng-portal) API supports GCM mode since Vista SP1 (see the `BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_GCM` constant given [on this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/cng-property-identifiers)).

Comment: Duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62802783/aes-gcm-on-delphi-with-authentication-tag-analogue-openssl-encrypt-from-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know at least two Open Source libraries how does:

- the reference code of the [late Wolfgang Ehrhardt](https://github.com/moe123/www.wolfgang-ehrhardt.de);
- our [SynCrypto](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/blob/master/SynCrypto.pas) library, from mORMot.

The later being faster in terms of performance.

Comment: I have just enhanced performance of the pascal code, and also included AES-NI and CLMUL opcodes support on Westmere+ CPUs (from 2010), in the mORMot2 fork - check https://github.com/synopse/mORMot2/commit/1120a80861d45b64e144f4d623328ed009b12e09